# pushViewController from Objective-C code to Swift in Swift project

Tags: ios, swift

I am working in Swift project and using both Swift as well as Objective-C code.
I know that to use Objective-C code in Swift project I need to add bridging header. That I already included and using Objective-C code effectively. To use Swift code in Objective-C I need to include `#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"` in .m file.

Now issue I am facing is that I am calling method `data.getLoadData()` in LauchViewController.swift method

```
    func navigate() {
    let data: Data = Data()
    data.getLoadData()
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(DisplayCarViewController(), animated: true)
}
```

Now I want to pushViewController to another Swift controller DisplayCarViewController, it has tableView which I have to fill with data.
Here is code of getLoadData()

```
- (void)getLoadData
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [spinner setCenter:CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / 2,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height / 2)];
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];

    AFOAuth1OneLeggedClient *clnt = [[AFOAuth1OneLeggedClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path] key:cosumer_key secret:cosumer_secret];
    [clnt getPath:@"products" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSLog(@"responseObject: %@\n operation: %@", [responseObject valueForKey:@"products"], operation);

            array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [array addObjectsFromArray: [responseObject valueForKey:@"products"]];

            NSLog(@"Array: %@", array);
            [spinner stopAnimating];
            DisplayCarViewController *controller = [[DisplayCarViewController alloc] init];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:true];
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error data: %@\n Error operation: %@",error, operation);
        [spinner stopAnimating];
    }];
}
```

The issue is that app stays at LauchViewController. Data is fetched successfully, but doest not move/push to DisplayCarViewController. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is

Comment: I want to push to another controller here DisplayCarViewController *controller = [[DisplayCarViewController alloc] init];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:true]; I am unable to do so.

Comment: What do you mean? What is the error/result?

Comment: There is no error, app stays at LauchViewController. and data is fetched successfully, but doest not move/push to DisplayCarViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getLoadData` method is inside Data class implementation. And this class doesn't look like UIViewController subclass. At least it shouldn't be according to the logic. I guess the best solution here will be to implement your `getLoadData` method like this:

```
- (void)getLoadDataWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSArray *data, NSError *error))completion
{
    AFOAuth1OneLeggedClient *clnt = [[AFOAuth1OneLeggedClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path] key:cosumer_key secret:cosumer_secret];
    [clnt getPath:@"products" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSLog(@"responseObject: %@\n operation: %@", [responseObject valueForKey:@"products"], operation);

            array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [array addObjectsFromArray: [responseObject valueForKey:@"products"]];

            NSLog(@"Array: %@", array);
            completion ? completion(array, nil) : nil;
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error data: %@\n Error operation: %@",error, operation);
        completion ? completion(nil, error) : nil;
    }];
}
```

And to implement your `navigate` method like this.

```
func navigate() {
    let data: Data = Data()

    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .WhiteLarge)
    spinner.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
    spinner.center = CGPointMake(screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height / 2)
    view.addSubview(spinner)
    spinner.startAnimating()

    data.getLoadData() {
        [unowned self] (data, error) in
        spinner.stopAnimating()
        if let data = data {
            let carVC = DisplayCarViewController()
            // init carVC with data somehow
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(carVC, animated: true)
        } else {
            // handle error somehow
        }
    }

}
```

I haven't tried this so the code might have some syntax errors.

Comment: Wow Thank you very much, i was stuck here for quite sometime, solved my issue. Thanks a ton. :)